# How to get Redundant result from Mysql In Clause?

Tags: mysql

I am facing one issue related to Mysql Query can anyone help me this.

Table 1

ID Column1

1 Hello

2 Hi

3 Bye

Table 2

ID Column1 Column2

1 XYZ 2,3,2 (These ids are from Table one)

Now I need to fetch table2 data with column2 actual values(ie. Hi,Bye,Hi).

Currently, the Query which I am using is

SELECT a.Column1, GROUP_CONCAT(b.Column2)

FROM Table1 a, Table2 b

WHERE FIND_IN_SET(b.id, (SELECT Column2 FROM `Table1` WHERE id =1))and b.id=1;

I am getting the result from this query but the problem is with the FIND_IN_SET Clause. if the ids are duplicate then it is returning the only unique value.

Can anyone help me with this, how can I get the values as per the passed argument.

If I am passing (2,3,2) then the result should be (Hi,Bye,Hi).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: can anyone ..help my out with above question